# Django rest framework request data is always null

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I just want to try simple Django rest framework code, I used APIVIEW and posted data through browser.

CODE:

```
class GetData(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            item_id = request.data.get('item_id')
            return Response({"return": "OK ","item_id":item_id})
        else:
            return Response({"return": "NOT OK "})
```

The above code should echo the item_id whatever i "POST"ed. but the result is always null.

POST data:

```
{ "item_id" : "3456787"}
```

result:

```
{"item_id":null,"return" :"OK "}
```

I don't understand where I went wrong. the above code works fine in my Loaclhost but does not work in production server.

Comment: What is the data you are posting? and what are the headers?

Comment: I am using browsable api. Using chrome browesr to post data. mediaType is `application/json`.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Isn't the data in request.body? if it's a dict: request.body.get('item_id') ?

Comment: @DA-- No, He is using DRF which parses request.body and puts it in request.data

Comment: @Naroju What is the Json you are posting? Looks like it is not getting any json

Comment: @Shaumux, isn't that only the case if the parsers are correctly configured?

Comment: `{ "item_id" : "3456787"}` this is the only  thing i post. I mentioned it in the question.

Comment: request.data.get('item_id') returns none, happens when you call get() on a dict, but the value key doesn't exist. Seems to me that the JSON wasn't pased by DRF. 

Can you print request.data ? Or check it in de debugger? It may be an empty dict.

Comment: @DA-- I tried to return request.data instead of item_id for the same post data. here is what it is returning `{
    "item_id": {
        "_content_type": "application/json",
        "_content": "{\r\n\r\n\"item_id\" : \"3456787\"\r\n\r\n}"
    },
    "return": "OK "
}`

Comment: @Naroju Did you put rest_framework in installed_apps?

Comment: @DA-- I see the data in the `request.data` but it is not getting parsed this way `request.data.get("item_d")`

Comment: Yes I did. @Shaumux

Comment: I am using django version 1.10.5. will this be any problem?

Comment: @Naroju, so `request.data.get('item_id')` gives you `{ "_content_type": "application/json", "_content": "{\r\n\r\n\"item_id\" : \"3456787\"\r\n\r\n}" }, "return": "OK " }` ?

Comment: No. I tried to print request.data it gives that `{ "item_id": { "_content_type": "application/json", "_content": "{\r\n\r\n\"item_id\" : \"3456787\"\r\n\r\n}" }, "return": "OK " }`

Comment: I just created a fresh project and everything is working and the output is what you expect

Comment: I downgraded my django version to 1.8 LTS. working on it... I will let you know what went wrong. thank you both of you.

Comment: @Naroju Check my answer I did it with latest django and DRF. Check if you can replicate

Answer (score 1):

Started with a fresh project with latest django and DRF and changed the following

app1/views.py

```
class GetData(APIView):
def post(self, request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item_id = request.data.get('item_id')
        return Response({"return": "OK ","item_id": item_id})
    else:
        return Response({"return": "NOT OK "})
```

only change in proj/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework'
]
```

app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from app1.views import GetData
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^test/', GetData.as_view())
]
```

Query:

```
curl -X Post http://localhost:8000/test/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "item_id":"3456787"}'
```

Result:

```
{"item_id":"3456787","return":"OK "}%
```

Comment: As I mentioned earlier in the question. It is working fine in the localhost but not in the production server. I found similar problem here https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3623 . It was a problem of apache configuration. but there was no correct solution there in the link

Comment: @Naroju, I have the same problem as it works properly in local and the same your problem in iis server.